# Internal Salesforce.com error when updating date field?

Tags: salesforce, runtime-error, apex

I'm getting

> Internal Salesforce.com error

I've tracked it to when I'm calling update on a contact that updates the birthday field.  Any idea why that may be happening?

Here is the top function that is called from the trigger

```
//Called from after update trigger
public static void onAfterUpdate(Map<Id,Contact> newContactMap, Map<Id, Contact> oldContactMap)
{
    ...
    cp.UpdateBirthdateOfContact();
    cp.updateContacts();
    ...
}
```

Here is the ContactProcesses class that has those functions

```
public class ContactProcesses  {
    ...
    public void UpdateBirthdateOfContact() {
            for(Contact c : givenContactList) {
                if(c.Birthday_Day__c != null && c.Birthday_Day__c != 'Unknown' && c.Birthday_Month__c != null && c.Birthday_Month__c != 'Unknown' && c.Birthday_Year__c != null && c.Birthday_Year__c != 'Unknown') {
                        Contact toUpdate = getContact(c.id);
                        System.debug('Starting parse...');
                        toUpdate.Birthdate = Date.parse(monthDict.get(c.Birthday_Month__c) + '/' + c.Birthday_Day__c + '/' + c.Birthday_Year__c);
                        System.debug('This is the birthdate: ' + String.valueOf(toUpdate.Birthdate));
                }
            }
    }

    ...

    public integer updateContacts() {
        Integer toReturn = 0;
        System.debug('Size is ' + updateContactList.size());
        if(updateContactList.size() > 0) System.debug('Contact is ' + updateContactList[0]);
        if(updateContactList.size() > 0) {
            update updateContactList; //Error here
            toReturn = updateContactList.size();
            updateContactList.clear();
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The error is being thrown when calling update on the contacts.

Here's some of the log leading up to the error

```
10:47:32.499 (3473484535)|METHOD_ENTRY|[312]|01p3F0000083em6|ContactProcesses.UpdateBirthdateOfContact()
10:47:32.499 (3473491521)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[335]|this|ContactProcesses|true|false
10:47:32.499 (3473529495)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[335]|this|{"givenContactList":"0x618bdcc8","oldContactMap":"0x2ca04f11","toCreateTaskLst":"0x3a02db51","updateAccountList":"0x3e2f50bd","updateContactList":"0x12e0c19c","updateMemDetails":"0x2d323294"}|0x530ffd91
10:47:32.499 (3473539265)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[335]
10:47:32.499 (3473560011)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[336]|Bytes:5
10:47:32.499 (3473576490)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[336]|c|Contact|true|false
10:47:32.499 (3475137229)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[336]|c|{"LastModifiedDate":"2020-08-04T17:47:33.000Z","HasOptedOutOfFax":false,"Email_Correspondence_Only__c":false,"pi__Needs_Score_Synced__c":false,"AC_HIdden_InProgress_Activities_For_Week__c":0,"Do_Not_Call_At_Work__c":false,"Is_US_Contact__c":false,"Is_Anonymous__c":false,"IsDeleted":false,"Telemarketing_Opt_Out__c":false,"HiddenFlag__c":false,"Ambassador_Mail_Opt_Out__c":false,"Gender__c":"Male","MailingCity":"Hollbrook","Wedding_Anniversary_Day__c":"Unknown","Mail_Opt_Out__c":false,"Birthday_Day__c":"3","Org_Closed__c":false,"Id":"0033F00000PlHl6QAF","Greeting__c":"Friend","Created_Date_ADF__c":"2020-06-19T00:00:00.000Z","Is_Masterworks_Scoring__c":false,"Wedding_Anniversary_Year__c":"Unknown","Exclude_from_New_Ministry_Friend_Contact__c":false,"Spouse_Birthday_Year__c":"Unknown","DoNotCall":false,"Faith_Justice_Opt_Out__c":false,"Wedding_Anniversary_Month__c":"Unknown","MailingCountry":"USA","MailingState":"OR","Spouse_Birthday_Month__c":"Unknown","Do_Not_Mail__c":false,"OwnerId":"005f4000003ptcBAAQ","Addressee__c":"Test Street Caps","RecordTypeId":"012f4000000d6nlAAA","Is_Not_Presumed_Deceased__c":false,"AC_HiddenTriggerDate__c":"2020-06-24T20:35:37.000Z","Number_of_Newsletters_NL__c":"Eligible to Receive  (8 more) ...","AC_Hidden_No_of_Open_Activities__c":0,"Likeminded_M_F__c":"Unknown","ADF_Foundation_Mail_Opt_Out__c":false,"Likeminded_Life__c":"Unknown","AC_HiddenForAmbassadorContact__c":false,"Is_Bad_Address__c":false,"AC_isCreatedAmbassador__c":false,"AC_Hidden_No_of_Closed_Events__c":0,"SystemModstamp":"2020-08-04T17:47:33.000Z","Import_From_RV1__c":false,"Appeals_Opt_Out__c":false,"Spouse_Birthday_Day__c":"Unknown","Age__c":14,"AccountId":"0013F00000YSUlmQAH","AC_UserName__c":"jdias@adflegal.org.j (7 more) ...","Spouse_Contact_Updated__c":false,"Birthday_Month__c":"April","CA_HiddenIsUserActive__c":false,"Address_Standardization_Status__c":"Standardization Pend (3 more) ...","AC_Duplicate_Contact_From_Ambassador__c":false,"Is_International_Contact__c":false,"Birthday_Year__c":"2006","Suffix__c":"Jr.","Is_Head_of_Household__c":false,"Faith_Justice__c":false,"CreatedById":"005f4000003ptcBAAQ","AC_Send_Ambasador_Captain_Email__c":false,"ADF_Duplicate_Check__c":false,"AC_Spouse_Interested_To_Be_Ambassador__c":false,"AC_Hidden_No_of_Open_Events__c":0,"IsEmailBounced":false,"Is_Email_Bounced__c":false,"HasOptedOutOfEmail":false,"Is_Spouse_Primary__c":false,"AMFEMs_Opt_Out__c":false,"Birthdate":"2006-04-03T00:00:00.000Z","Do_Not_Auto_Update__c":false,"AC_Total_Amount_Paid_By_Contact__c":0.00,"Former_Account__c":false,"Is_Presumed_Deceased__c":false,"CreatedDate":"2020-06-19T20:35:37.000Z","Received_New_Donor_Package__c":false,"LastName":"Test Street Caps","MailingStreet":"Crater\r\nGreat\r\nLakes","Is_Deceased__c":false,"AC_HIdden_Closed_Activities_For_Week__c":0,"Mailing_Address_Type__c":"Work","AC_Send_Ambassador_Reg_Email__c":false,"Receipts_Only_No_Other_Mail__c":false,"Contact_Record_ID__c":"CON-1309782","AC_HiddenYearTemplate__c":"2020","Is_Spouse_Deceased__c":false,"Account_Matches_Employee_Giving__c":false,"AC_Total_Amount_Paid_By_Ambassador_Conta__c":0.00,"Application_Shield_Contact__c":false,"Receipts_Opt_Out__c":false,"Is_Legal_Contact__c":false,"Contact_18_Character_ID__c":"0033F00000PlHl6QAF","Newsletter_NL_Opt_Out__c":false,"International_Dialing_Code__c":"1","Duplicate_Match_Check_Status__c":"Needs Check","Do_Not_Email__c":false,"AC_IsEmailSent__c":false,"AC_Hidden_No_of_InProgress_Tasks__c":0,"Email_Appeals__c":false,"Acknowledgement_Sent__c":false,"pi__pardot_hard_bounced__c":false,"AC_Hidden_No_of_Closed_Activities__c":0,"Pillars_of_Freedom_Mail_Opt_Out__c":false,"LastModifiedById":"005f4000003ptcBAAQ","Is_VIP__c":false,"Likeminded_Religious_Liberty__c":"Unknown"}|0x2b45fd99
10:47:32.499 (3475198729)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[336]
10:47:32.499 (3475248195)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[337]
10:47:32.499 (3475250525)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[338]
10:47:32.499 (3475263262)|METHOD_ENTRY|[338]|01p3F0000083em6|ContactProcesses.getContact(Id)
10:47:32.499 (3475273302)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[445]|this|ContactProcesses|true|false
10:47:32.499 (3475312987)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[445]|this|{"givenContactList":"0x618bdcc8","oldContactMap":"0x2ca04f11","toCreateTaskLst":"0x3a02db51","updateAccountList":"0x3e2f50bd","updateContactList":"0x12e0c19c","updateMemDetails":"0x2d323294"}|0x530ffd91
10:47:32.499 (3475321537)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[445]|conId|Id|false|false
10:47:32.499 (3475567614)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[445]|conId|"0033F00000PlHl6QAF"
10:47:32.499 (3475581235)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[445]
10:47:32.499 (3475617212)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[447]|Bytes:5
10:47:32.499 (3475640482)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[447]|c|null|
10:47:32.499 (3475650569)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[447]
10:47:32.499 (3475653796)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[452]
10:47:32.499 (3475688973)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[452]|Bytes:4
10:47:32.499 (3475770784)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[452]|this.Id|"0033F00000PlHl6QAF"|0x340769d5
10:47:32.499 (3475797188)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[452]|c|Contact|true|false
10:47:32.499 (3475822063)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[452]|c|{"Id":"0033F00000PlHl6QAF"}|0x340769d5
10:47:32.499 (3475832564)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[453]
10:47:32.499 (3475850099)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
10:47:32.499 (3475864308)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[455]
10:47:32.499 (3475871584)|METHOD_EXIT|[338]|01p3F0000083em6|ContactProcesses.getContact(Id)
10:47:32.499 (3475882926)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[338]|toUpdate|Contact|true|false
10:47:32.499 (3475905588)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[338]|toUpdate|{"Id":"0033F00000PlHl6QAF"}|0x340769d5
10:47:32.499 (3475914187)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[339]
10:47:32.499 (3475932368)|USER_DEBUG|[339]|DEBUG|Starting parse...
10:47:32.499 (3475952357)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[340]
10:47:32.499 (3476009777)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[EXTERNAL]|this|{"givenContactList":"0x618bdcc8","oldContactMap":"0x2ca04f11","toCreateTaskLst":"0x3a02db51","updateAccountList":"0x3e2f50bd","updateContactList":"0x12e0c19c","updateMemDetails":"0x2d323294"}|0x530ffd91
10:47:32.499 (3476025773)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[18]
10:47:32.499 (3476029080)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[19]
10:47:32.499 (3476056285)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[19]|Bytes:4
10:47:32.499 (3476072535)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[19]|toReturn|Map<String,Integer>|true|false
10:47:32.499 (3476097545)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[19]|toReturn|{}|0x2751196a
10:47:32.499 (3476107963)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[20]
10:47:32.499 (3476125943)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[20]|Bytes:4
10:47:32.499 (3476138754)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:-4
10:47:32.499 (3476150759)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[21]
10:47:32.499 (3476162098)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[21]|Bytes:4
10:47:32.499 (3476170527)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:-4
10:47:32.499 (3476180780)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[22]
10:47:32.499 (3476191046)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[22]|Bytes:4
10:47:32.499 (3476199580)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:-4
10:47:32.499 (3476210315)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[23]
10:47:32.499 (3476220299)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[23]|Bytes:4
10:47:32.499 (3476226521)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:-4
10:47:32.499 (3476237526)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[24]
10:47:32.499 (3476246385)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[24]|Bytes:4
10:47:32.499 (3476254517)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:-4
10:47:32.499 (3476264530)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[25]
10:47:32.499 (3476274058)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[25]|Bytes:4
10:47:32.499 (3476282039)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:-4
10:47:32.499 (3476291755)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[26]
10:47:32.499 (3476301126)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[26]|Bytes:4
10:47:32.499 (3476308394)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:-4
10:47:32.499 (3476318556)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[27]
10:47:32.499 (3476328013)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[27]|Bytes:4
10:47:32.499 (3476335088)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:-4
10:47:32.499 (3476345229)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[28]
10:47:32.499 (3476353675)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[28]|Bytes:4
10:47:32.499 (3476361393)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:-4
10:47:32.499 (3476371677)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[29]
10:47:32.499 (3476380864)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[29]|Bytes:4
10:47:32.499 (3476389683)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:-4
10:47:32.499 (3476399458)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[30]
10:47:32.499 (3476408111)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[30]|Bytes:4
10:47:32.499 (3476415822)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:-4
10:47:32.499 (3476425953)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[31]
10:47:32.499 (3476434387)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[31]|Bytes:4
10:47:32.499 (3476441942)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:-4
10:47:32.499 (3476451891)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[33]
10:47:32.499 (3476502570)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[340]|Bytes:1
10:47:32.499 (3476534200)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[340]|Bytes:8
10:47:32.499 (3476607951)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[340]|Bytes:4
10:47:32.499 (3476692126)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[340]|this.Birthdate|"2006-04-03T00:00:00.000Z"|0x340769d5
10:47:32.499 (3476701462)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[341]
10:47:32.499 (3476730202)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[341]|Bytes:10
10:47:32.499 (3476749950)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[341]|Bytes:33
10:47:32.499 (3476761112)|USER_DEBUG|[341]|DEBUG|This is the birthdate: 2006-04-03
10:47:32.499 (3476779353)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[336]|Bytes:5
10:47:32.499 (3476794269)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[336]|c|null|
10:47:32.499 (3476804168)|METHOD_EXIT|[312]|01p3F0000083em6|ContactProcesses.UpdateBirthdateOfContact()
10:47:32.499 (3476810310)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[314]
10:47:32.499 (3476817580)|METHOD_ENTRY|[314]|01p3F0000083em6|ContactProcesses.UpdateFieldsOfDeceasedContact()
10:47:32.499 (3476824211)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[358]|this|ContactProcesses|true|false
10:47:32.499 (3476861730)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[358]|this|{"givenContactList":"0x618bdcc8","oldContactMap":"0x2ca04f11","toCreateTaskLst":"0x3a02db51","updateAccountList":"0x3e2f50bd","updateContactList":"0x12e0c19c","updateMemDetails":"0x2d323294"}|0x530ffd91
10:47:32.499 (3476871226)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[358]
10:47:32.499 (3476891333)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[359]|Bytes:5
10:47:32.499 (3476907467)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[359]|c|Contact|true|false
10:47:32.499 (3478458939)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[359]|c|{"LastModifiedDate":"2020-08-04T17:47:33.000Z","HasOptedOutOfFax":false,"Email_Correspondence_Only__c":false,"pi__Needs_Score_Synced__c":false,"AC_HIdden_InProgress_Activities_For_Week__c":0,"Do_Not_Call_At_Work__c":false,"Is_US_Contact__c":false,"Is_Anonymous__c":false,"IsDeleted":false,"Telemarketing_Opt_Out__c":false,"HiddenFlag__c":false,"Ambassador_Mail_Opt_Out__c":false,"Gender__c":"Male","MailingCity":"Hollbrook","Wedding_Anniversary_Day__c":"Unknown","Mail_Opt_Out__c":false,"Birthday_Day__c":"3","Org_Closed__c":false,"Id":"0033F00000PlHl6QAF","Greeting__c":"Friend","Created_Date_ADF__c":"2020-06-19T00:00:00.000Z","Is_Masterworks_Scoring__c":false,"Wedding_Anniversary_Year__c":"Unknown","Exclude_from_New_Ministry_Friend_Contact__c":false,"Spouse_Birthday_Year__c":"Unknown","DoNotCall":false,"Faith_Justice_Opt_Out__c":false,"Wedding_Anniversary_Month__c":"Unknown","MailingCountry":"USA","MailingState":"OR","Spouse_Birthday_Month__c":"Unknown","Do_Not_Mail__c":false,"OwnerId":"005f4000003ptcBAAQ","Addressee__c":"Test Street Caps","RecordTypeId":"012f4000000d6nlAAA","Is_Not_Presumed_Deceased__c":false,"AC_HiddenTriggerDate__c":"2020-06-24T20:35:37.000Z","Number_of_Newsletters_NL__c":"Eligible to Receive  (8 more) ...","AC_Hidden_No_of_Open_Activities__c":0,"Likeminded_M_F__c":"Unknown","ADF_Foundation_Mail_Opt_Out__c":false,"Likeminded_Life__c":"Unknown","AC_HiddenForAmbassadorContact__c":false,"Is_Bad_Address__c":false,"AC_isCreatedAmbassador__c":false,"AC_Hidden_No_of_Closed_Events__c":0,"SystemModstamp":"2020-08-04T17:47:33.000Z","Import_From_RV1__c":false,"Appeals_Opt_Out__c":false,"Spouse_Birthday_Day__c":"Unknown","Age__c":14,"AccountId":"0013F00000YSUlmQAH","AC_UserName__c":"jdias@adflegal.org.j (7 more) ...","Spouse_Contact_Updated__c":false,"Birthday_Month__c":"April","CA_HiddenIsUserActive__c":false,"Address_Standardization_Status__c":"Standardization Pend (3 more) ...","AC_Duplicate_Contact_From_Ambassador__c":false,"Is_International_Contact__c":false,"Birthday_Year__c":"2006","Suffix__c":"Jr.","Is_Head_of_Household__c":false,"Faith_Justice__c":false,"CreatedById":"005f4000003ptcBAAQ","AC_Send_Ambasador_Captain_Email__c":false,"ADF_Duplicate_Check__c":false,"AC_Spouse_Interested_To_Be_Ambassador__c":false,"AC_Hidden_No_of_Open_Events__c":0,"IsEmailBounced":false,"Is_Email_Bounced__c":false,"HasOptedOutOfEmail":false,"Is_Spouse_Primary__c":false,"AMFEMs_Opt_Out__c":false,"Birthdate":"2006-04-03T00:00:00.000Z","Do_Not_Auto_Update__c":false,"AC_Total_Amount_Paid_By_Contact__c":0.00,"Former_Account__c":false,"Is_Presumed_Deceased__c":false,"CreatedDate":"2020-06-19T20:35:37.000Z","Received_New_Donor_Package__c":false,"LastName":"Test Street Caps","MailingStreet":"Crater\r\nGreat\r\nLakes","Is_Deceased__c":false,"AC_HIdden_Closed_Activities_For_Week__c":0,"Mailing_Address_Type__c":"Work","AC_Send_Ambassador_Reg_Email__c":false,"Receipts_Only_No_Other_Mail__c":false,"Contact_Record_ID__c":"CON-1309782","AC_HiddenYearTemplate__c":"2020","Is_Spouse_Deceased__c":false,"Account_Matches_Employee_Giving__c":false,"AC_Total_Amount_Paid_By_Ambassador_Conta__c":0.00,"Application_Shield_Contact__c":false,"Receipts_Opt_Out__c":false,"Is_Legal_Contact__c":false,"Contact_18_Character_ID__c":"0033F00000PlHl6QAF","Newsletter_NL_Opt_Out__c":false,"International_Dialing_Code__c":"1","Duplicate_Match_Check_Status__c":"Needs Check","Do_Not_Email__c":false,"AC_IsEmailSent__c":false,"AC_Hidden_No_of_InProgress_Tasks__c":0,"Email_Appeals__c":false,"Acknowledgement_Sent__c":false,"pi__pardot_hard_bounced__c":false,"AC_Hidden_No_of_Closed_Activities__c":0,"Pillars_of_Freedom_Mail_Opt_Out__c":false,"LastModifiedById":"005f4000003ptcBAAQ","Is_VIP__c":false,"Likeminded_Religious_Liberty__c":"Unknown"}|0x2b45fd99
10:47:32.499 (3479014072)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[359]
10:47:32.499 (3479034935)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[360]
10:47:32.499 (3479052720)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[359]|Bytes:5
10:47:32.499 (3479073822)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[359]|c|null|
10:47:32.499 (3479084396)|METHOD_EXIT|[314]|01p3F0000083em6|ContactProcesses.UpdateFieldsOfDeceasedContact()
10:47:32.499 (3479090908)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[315]
10:47:32.499 (3479097792)|METHOD_ENTRY|[315]|01p3F0000083em6|ContactProcesses.updateContacts()
10:47:32.499 (3479105112)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[407]|this|ContactProcesses|true|false
10:47:32.499 (3479149643)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[407]|this|{"givenContactList":"0x618bdcc8","oldContactMap":"0x2ca04f11","toCreateTaskLst":"0x3a02db51","updateAccountList":"0x3e2f50bd","updateContactList":"0x12e0c19c","updateMemDetails":"0x2d323294"}|0x530ffd91
10:47:32.499 (3479159316)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[407]
10:47:32.499 (3479161462)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[408]
10:47:32.499 (3479166852)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[408]|toReturn|Integer|false|false
10:47:32.499 (3479175124)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[408]|Bytes:4
10:47:32.499 (3479183719)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[408]|toReturn|0
10:47:32.499 (3479188834)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[409]
10:47:32.499 (3479218454)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[409]|Bytes:1
10:47:32.499 (3479232786)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[409]|Bytes:9
10:47:32.499 (3479243875)|USER_DEBUG|[409]|DEBUG|Size is 1
10:47:32.499 (3479261193)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[410]
10:47:32.499 (3479271967)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[410]|Bytes:12
10:47:32.499 (3479325703)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[410]|Bytes:62
10:47:32.499 (3479340890)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[410]|Bytes:73
10:47:32.499 (3479349099)|USER_DEBUG|[410]|DEBUG|Contact is Contact:{Id=0033F00000PlHl6QAF, Birthdate=2006-04-03 00:00:00}
10:47:32.499 (3479365497)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[411]
10:47:32.499 (3479368054)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[412]
10:47:32.499 (3479418056)|DML_BEGIN|[412]|Op:Update|Type:Contact|Rows:1
10:47:32.499 (3479456828)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
10:47:32.499 (3498519660)|DML_END|[412]
10:47:33.499 (3499175213)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
```

Comment: What triggers or processes do you have on that field?

Comment: I'm calling that update in the after update trigger of the contact object.  Is it due to the recursive nature of it?

Comment: Certainly possible. Can you post some code or screenshots?

Comment: I added some code

Comment: How about a log? Can you post some of that please?

Comment: I added some of the log leading up to the error

Comment: Are you using some kind of a base case? Or are you calling the trigger for every update to contact and then updating contact in the trigger? (This would be an endless loop).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use the static class property pattern to avoid trigger endless recursion.

See here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000Qtw4IAC